# How to pass the data from the fragment to bottom sheet in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to get data from the fragment listview and view it in a bottom sheet layout. I want to view like above attached image. Please help me.[image]

I done code for viewing the bottom sheet ,when user clicks the listview items the bottom sheet will be opened.In the bottom sheet the listview item details in the fragment should be viewed in a bottom sheet.The code for my project is attached below.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_log, container, false);
    callLogList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.callLogList);
    contactPhoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.missedImage);

    final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
    View bottomSheetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet,null);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);


   String[] textString = new String[]{"Play", "Share", "Call", "add Notes","Add To Block","Delete"};
  int[]  drawableIds = new int[]{R.drawable.play_icon, R.drawable.share_icon, R.drawable.call_icon, R.drawable.add_notes_icon,
            R.drawable.block_icon,R.drawable.delete_icon};

    final ListView listbottom = (ListView)bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.listBottomSheets);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,  textString, drawableIds);
    listbottom.setAdapter(adapter);




    listbottom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {



            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"playing the song",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"sharing the song",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"deleting the song",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"blocking the song",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"nothing selected ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }

        }
    });


    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) bottomSheetView.getParent());
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(320);

    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hidden",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });

    callLogList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            bottomSheetDialog.show();
        }
    });

    setRetainInstance(true);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever the data you have that you want to pass from your main listview to bottomsheet list, just pass those data in the bottomsheet adapter .

here in the line

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,  textString, drawableIds);
```

make this change

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, textString, drawableIds, myDataArrayListToDisplayInBottomSheet);
```

where `myDataArrayListToDisplayInBottomSheet`
is the `ArrayList<>`  of the data that you have to display in the bottomSheet.

And in you `CustomAdapter`, use use this data to display accordingly.

Comment: "myDataArrayListToDisplayInBottomSheet "this means the arraylist data of listview which is placed in the fragment

Comment: Indeed, if that is the data that you want to display in the bottomSheet.

Comment: @sohaibkarim how can we get data from fragment to bottomsheet and pass to activity

Answer (score 6):

You can pass entire contact object to bottom sheet fragment by to serializing and deserialize your contact object.

```
public class DetailFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{ 
  private static final String DESCRIBABLE_KEY = "describable_key";
  private ContactModel contactToShow ;

  public static DetailFragment newInstance(ContactModel modelToPass) {
    DetailFragment bottomSheetFragment = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(DESCRIBABLE_KEY, modelToPass);
    bottomSheetFragment .setArguments(bundle);

    return bottomSheetFragment ;
  } 

  @Override 
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Deserilize contact object
    contactToShow = (ContactModel) getArguments().getSerializable(
        DESCRIBABLE_KEY);

    // The rest of your code to display detail of bill Gates

}
```

You can afterward start bottomsheet fragment doing something like:

```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity) context)
                            .getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();

DetailFragment.newInstance(billGatesContactObject).show(transaction, "dialog_playback");
```

You can see working example here

https://github.com/dkim0419/SoundRecorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/danielkim/soundrecorder/fragments/PlaybackFragment.java

Another dirty solution is to keep contact object in host Activity class and set and fetch contact object using  `((HostActivity) getActivity).getContact()` and `((HostActivity) getActivity).setContact(billGates)` method.